# Struggling with CSS: Outer container is snapping down to the top margin an inner container. Why?

Tags: html, css

Here is my url: http://www.chs07reunion.info  (its a work in progress)

If you follow the link you should see what I'm talking about.  I have an outer container set at:

```
#headerandbg {
    background-color: #4A514D;
    width: 960px;
    background-image: url(Headfonts2.jpg);
    height: 1280px;
    **margin-top: 0;**
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

With an inner container at:

```
#corkbg {
    width: 880px;
    background-color: #C90;
    **margin-top: 140px;**
    margin-right: 40px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    background-image: url(cork5.jpg);
    height: 1100px;
}
```

The pages html has #headerandbg followed by #corkbg:

```
<body>
    <div id="headerandbg">
        <div id="corkbg">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

On my browser both containers are lining up with a gap on the top and the top-margin height is dependant on the inner container (currently set at 140px).  If I take out the inner, the outer container goes back to the top (where I want it).  Any suggestions?

Comment: It's a case of collapsing margins: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins

Answer (score 2):

Try using padding instead. Margins are supposed to collapse when there is no content to "move away".

```
#headerandbg {
    padding-top: 140px;
}

#corkbg {
    margin-top: 0; /* or remove this */
}
```

Works for me in Firefox 4.

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow: auto;` to `#headerandbg`:

```
#headerandbg {
    overflow: auto;

    background-color: #4A514D;
    width: 960px;
    background-image: url(Headfonts2.jpg);
    height: 1280px;
    **margin-top: 0;**
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
```